# How to Retrieve USB String Descriptors on UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, usb

I need to develop a UWP application to communicate with a USB device which exposes two USB interface. One is HID interface and the other one is a proprietary interface which is supported by WinUSB driver. I could communicate with each interface successfully using Microsoft provided "[Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice)" and "[Windows.Devices.Usb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb)" namespaces respectively.

My problem is there is no way to identify these two interfaces exposed by the device belongs to one physical device. If I were able to retrieve the devices string descriptors from each interface then I could have done this by matching the iSerial field of the device. This is how I did it in Windows Desktop version of the application.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the devices string descriptors that you want to retrieve? It seems you can get the identifier for the given HID device using the [HidDevice Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice#properties-), and get USB descriptors from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-get-usb-descriptors--uwp-app-).

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT Well, for an example I would like to retrieve iSerialNumber of the device. Usually, this is the String descriptor #3 of an HID device. I tried to get the required descriptors using the Microsoft documentation you have provided but failed. Maybe I'm missing. something here. Thank you for the comment.